# Wordpress loop goes into infinite loop when adjust

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, loops

I am using KLEO theme for my work.

I am trying to filter posts by category when the date archive is called.

I did this by modifying the core files of the theme. However when the code is run it goes into infinite loop and definitely doesn't produce the results required.

e.g. if I go to localhost/wordpress/2014/06?category=events it should show posts on that date that are only from this category. However it goes into the infinite loop.

The modified code is here:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Archive pages
 *
 * Used to display archive-type pages if nothing more specific matches a query.
 * For example, puts together date-based pages if no date.php file exists.
 *
 * If you'd like to further customize these archive views, you may create a
 * new template file for each specific one. For example, Twenty Fourteen
 * already has tag.php for Tag archives, category.php for Category archives,
 * and author.php for Author archives.
 *
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Kleo
 * @since Kleo 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

<?php
//Specific class for post listing */
$blog_type = sq_option('blog_type','masonry');
$template_classes = $blog_type . '-listing';
if ($blog_type == 'standard' && sq_option('blog_meta_status', 1) == 1) { $template_classes .= ' with-meta'; }
add_filter('kleo_main_template_classes', create_function('$cls','$cls .=" posts-listing '.$template_classes.'"; return $cls;'));
?>

<?php get_template_part('page-parts/general-title-section'); ?>

<?php get_template_part('page-parts/general-before-wrap'); ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php 
    if ($blog_type == 'masonry') {
        echo '<div class="row">'
            .'<div class="grid-posts kleo-isotope masonry">';
    }
    ?>

    <?php



    function the_loop($the_query){


            // Start the Loop.
            while ( $the_query ) : the_post();

                /*
                 * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
                 * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
                 * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                 */

                if ($blog_type == 'masonry') {
                    get_template_part( 'page-parts/post-content-masonry');
                 }
                else {
                     get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
                }


            endwhile;
    }
            if( is_date() ){


                            if(isset($_GET["category"])){

                                $category_slug = trim($_GET["category"]);
                                $args=array('category_name = '.$category_slug.'');
                                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                                $lol =$the_query->have_posts();
                                the_loop($lol);



                            }

            }

            else{

                $the_query=have_posts();
                the_loop($the_query);

            }

            ?>

            <?php
            if ($blog_type == 'masonry') { 
                echo '</div>'
                    .'</div>';
            }
            ?>

            <?php
            // page navigation.
            kleo_pagination();

        else :
            // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
            get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

        endif;
    ?>

<?php get_template_part('page-parts/general-after-wrap'); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Please help!!!

Comment: There's no place in your while loop where you modify `$the_query`. So it loops forever.

Comment: Its built in wordpress functions ( e.g. have_posts() and the_post()) that should help monitor the while loop?